# Instagram cannot login from AWS & DigitalOcean

Tags: python, instagram

I wrote a simple login script try to login to Instagram from a server

```
import requests
import pprint

INSTAGRAM_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
IG_ACCOUNTS = [
    {'username': 'username1', 'password': 'pass1'},
    {'username': 'username2', 'password': 'pass2'},
]

def login(username, password):
    login_url = INSTAGRAM_URL + '/accounts/login/ajax/'
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = { 'user-agent': USER_AGENT }
    session.headers.update({'Referer': INSTAGRAM_URL})
    req = session.get(INSTAGRAM_URL)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
    login = session.post(login_url, data={'username': username, 'password': password}, allow_redirects=True)
    print('login: ')
    pprint.pprint(login)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
    cookies = login.cookies
    results = login.json()
    print('login results')
    pprint.pprint(results)
    if (results['authenticated'] == False):
        return False, None
    return True, cookies

login(IG_ACCOUNTS[0]['username'], IG_ACCOUNTS[0]['password'])
```

but I get an error

```
HTTP status: 200

{
    'error_type': 'generic_request_error',
    'errors': {'error': ['Sorry, there was a problem with your request.']},
    'status': 'ok'
}
```

But when I run this script from local machine, it works pretty well.

```
{
    'user': True,
    'status': 'ok',
    'userId': '12345678910',
    'authenticated': True,
    'reactivated': True
}
```

### Update: Apr 26, 2018 17:10 UTC+8

I noticed Instagram blocked the ip address, even I try login with [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), I get the same error.

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: Maybe. Instagram blocked this server.

Comment: yea, i think so

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: I just bouht two weeks ago. I tried to create almost more than 2000 times. Only 29 accounts created by using proxy. it's not good for me